# Mid 2012 Macbook Air - upgrade RAM from 4Gb?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, memory

I’ve got a Mid-2012 Macbook Air that I changed out the SSD to 256Gb using the OWC Aura product. No problems at all – but it still only has 4Gb of ram and sucks it up pretty quickly now I have installed Sierra!

8gb was a preconfigured option on these models and from what I can tell the RAM is soldered in.

Has anyone upgraded one of these, and can you tell me how and using what RAM?

Thanks!

Phil in New Zealand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, but I'm having the same problem. With the relative speed of SSD memory, which this model has,it would seem feasible to have an app that could set aside a bit of the drive into a "pseudo RAM". Maybe not as effective as pure RAM, but might overcome the barrier.

Anybody aware of anything like this?

Comment: I was hoping that was possible too. Be sure and post if you find one and I'll do the same.

Maybe someone needs to build one?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the RAM on the MacBook Air is soldered in so you won't be able to upgrade it without breaking the computer. You need to make sure the amount of RAM is enough when you buy the machine.

<sub>If you don't mind you can downgrade the OS (the lowest you can get on 2012 MBA is 10.7.4), that will probably reduce the amount of RAM needed.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, Tom - I thought there was plenty of RAM at 8 Gigs - 5 years ago. Disappointed now I ended up with Sierra when I reinstalled the OS from online. Seemed to be all I could get on the AppStore - sure I can find a retro version somewhere but it might be hard to go back.

The best way I've found to cope is a Chrome extension called One Tab - crowds all your open tabs into one page of links. Gives me back a Gig every time, good if you're habitually open tab mad like me.

Answer (score -1):

looks like someones doing it. just where to get the ram from 
https://youtu.be/CTsEJ49LLsQ